adobe illustrator scripting, null is not object after making live paint group
I have a main script that calls many other scripts for specified conditions
the main idea is to iterates over an arabic calligraphy page and cut every letter by calling a specific script for every letter(i have the page as text, so i know the the asci of the current letter in the AI page) using tesseract-OCR for handling the best place for adding a line and finally make live paint group, so the letter will be cut
make sure that in arabic most of letters are connected and the writing is form right to left
The problem: when calling the main script an error is rising in the called letter script(null is not object) in the line: selection[0].translate(0,0); but when i call each letter_script alone it performs everything normally
the error line53 image
this is the code of one of the called letter_scripts:
var doc = app.activeDocument;
var ahrofLayer = doc.layers[0];
selection = null;
var ConfidenceTable = [];
var countTab = 0;

var width = 0.5; // start cutting after 1pt for group 1
var stop = false;
var NbFalseCut = 0;

var VerticalCutting = true;
var CuttingModeChanged1 = false;

// declaration variables
var item, nbItem, CuttingLayer, bounds, linePath, Font, psm, bond1, bond2, cuttingitem, imageFileCapture, pngOptions, CommandFile, OutputTextFile, i, NewTextForNewImage;
var tab = [];
// declaration variables

while (true) {
    item = ahrofLayer.pageItems[0];
    nbItem = 2;
    if (item.typename == 'CompoundPathItem') {
        nbItem = 3;
    }
    CuttingLayer = doc.layers.add();
    item.duplicate(CuttingLayer, ElementPlacement.PLACEATEND);
    item = CuttingLayer.pageItems[0];
    bounds = item.geometricBounds;
    linePath = CuttingLayer.pathItems.add();

    if (VerticalCutting == true) {

        Font = "1", psm = 10; // 10 not 13 in this group
        width += 0.3;
        linePath.setEntirePath([[bounds[2] - width, bounds[1]], [bounds[2] - width, bounds[3]]]); // vertical cutting
    }
    if (VerticalCutting == false) {
        Font = "1_2", psm = 10; // 10 not 13 in this group
        if (CuttingModeChanged1 == false) {
            width = 2;
            ConfidenceTable = [];
            countTab = 0;
            CuttingModeChanged1 = true;
        }
        width += 0.3;
        linePath.setEntirePath([[bounds[2] - 10, bounds[1] - width], [bounds[2], bounds[1] - width]]); // vertical cutting // -10 width of hae
    }

    linePath.selected = true;
    item.selected = true;
    app.executeMenuCommand('group');
    app.executeMenuCommand('Make Planet X');
    selection[0].translate(0, 0);
    app.executeMenuCommand('Expand Planet X');
    app.executeMenuCommand('ungroup');
    app.executeMenuCommand('ungroup');
    selection = null;

    // alert(doc.layers[0].pageItems.length);
    if (CuttingLayer.pageItems.length == nbItem) {
        // for arrange the item in cutting layer
        bond1 = CuttingLayer.pageItems[0].geometricBounds;
        bond2 = CuttingLayer.pageItems[1].geometricBounds;
        if (bond1[0] < bond2[0]) {
            CuttingLayer.pageItems[1].move(CuttingLayer, ElementPlacement.PLACEATBEGINNING);
        }

        ahrofLayer.visible = false;
        CuttingLayer.pageItems[1].remove();

        cuttingitem = CuttingLayer.pageItems[0];
        imageFileCapture = new File('A:/capture.png');
        pngOptions = new ImageCaptureOptions();
        pngOptions.antiAliasing = true;
        pngOptions.resolution = 2400; // zoom
        doc.imageCapture(imageFileCapture, cuttingitem.visibleBounds, pngOptions);

        ahrofLayer.visible = true;

        // we need wait to finish capture
        while (imageFileCapture.exists == false) {
            $.sleep(500);
        }
        $.sleep(500);

        CommandFile = File('A:/Command.bat');
        if (CommandFile.open("w")) {
         
            var batchContent = '@echo off\n' +
                               'cd /D A:\n' + 
                               'tesseract capture.png OutputText --tessdata-dir "C:\\Program Files\\Tesseract-OCR\\tessdata" -l ' + Font + ' --psm '  + psm + ' tsv\n' +
                               'exit';
            CommandFile.write(batchContent);
            CommandFile.close();
        }
        CommandFile.execute();

        // wait to finish writing in output text file
        $.sleep(700);

        OutputTextFile = File('A:/OutputText.tsv');
        if (OutputTextFile.open("r")) {
           
            tab = [];
            for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                OutputTextFile.readln();
            }
            tab = OutputTextFile.readln().split("\t"); // split according to tabs space
            ConfidenceTable[countTab] = [parseFloat(tab[10]), width];
            if (ConfidenceTable.length > 1) {
                if (ConfidenceTable[countTab][0] <= ConfidenceTable[countTab - 1][0] && ConfidenceTable[countTab - 1][0] > 50) {
                    stop = true;
                }
            } // if the confidence starts to decrease stop // !!! this may not work well
            countTab++;
        }
        imageFileCapture.remove(); // delete the image capture
        OutputTextFile.open("w"); // delete the text file content
        OutputTextFile.close();
    }
    CuttingLayer.remove();
    if (stop || width > 6) break; // for stop safely and ending while loop 
    if (width > 5) VerticalCutting = false; // switch to horizontal cutting (second if statement)
}

// alert(ConfidenceTable);
ConfidenceTable.sort(function (a, b) {
    return b[0] - a[0];
}); // sort from large to small
item = ahrofLayer.pageItems[0];
linePath = doc.layers[0].pathItems.add();

if (CuttingModeChanged1 == false) {
    linePath.setEntirePath([[bounds[2] - ConfidenceTable[0][1], bounds[1]], [bounds[2] - ConfidenceTable[0][1], bounds[3]]]);
}
if (CuttingModeChanged1 == true) {
    linePath.setEntirePath([[bounds[2] - 10, bounds[1] - ConfidenceTable[0][1]], [bounds[2], bounds[1] - ConfidenceTable[0][1]]]);
}

linePath.selected = true;
item.selected = true;
app.executeMenuCommand('group');
app.executeMenuCommand('Make Planet X');

    selection[0].translate(0, 0);

app.executeMenuCommand('Expand Planet X');
app.executeMenuCommand('ungroup');
app.executeMenuCommand('ungroup');
selection = null;


i tried to access the permissions and enabling them for the folders but didnt worked.
this is the whole code of the main script:
// Open the Quran file from the specified path
var QuranFile = File('A:/36_Text.txt');

function arrayIncludes(arr, val) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] === val) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

if (QuranFile.open("r")) {
    // Get the active document and its layers
    var doc = app.activeDocument;
    var HarakatLayer = doc.layers[0]; // Layer for Harakat (diacritical marks)
    var ahrofLayer = doc.layers[1]; // Layer for Quran text
    var ahrof = ahrofLayer.pageItems; // All items in the Quran text layer
    var len = ahrof.length; // Number of items

// Read the Quran file line by line and split the text into words
var QuranFileText = QuranFile.readln(); // Read the page as one line

var words = QuranFileText.split(" "); // Split the line into words

    var wordIndex = 0; // Index for words
    var currentAsci; // ASCII value of characters
    var Shape; // Shape type for cutting depend on the position of the letter within the word
    var prevIsMonfasel = false; // Flag for separate letters
    var StopAt; // Variable to determine stop point
    var LastLetterAsci; // ASCII value of the last letter
    var BeforeLastLetter; // ASCII value of the second last letter

// make sure that in Ai, the items in the page are processed from top left to bottom right,
// but since we have sorted the path from right to left the above rule was changed
//so in iteration we take every path form right to left.  but in the scope of one path
//the points are calculated form left to right, this forced us to calculate depending on
// the the right edge boundary, for cut the first letter in the path, except in case of ي ى
// when it is the last letter, we first cut the last letter first, then began with first


    OUTER_LOOP: for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        var moved = false; // Flag to check if item is moved

    if (words[wordIndex].length > 1) {
        BeforeLastLetter = words[wordIndex][words[wordIndex].length - 2].charCodeAt();
    }

    if (words[wordIndex].length > 0) {
        LastLetterAsci = words[wordIndex][words[wordIndex].length - 1].charCodeAt();
    }
        // in arabic the index starts from right to left
 
        // Letters that are monfasel (separate)                                                   
        var stopAtZero = [1575, 1583, 1584, 1585, 1586, 1608, 1569, 1572];// seperate letters// not connected with the next letter
       // ز و ذ د ؤ ء ا ر
        var StopAt = 1; // Default stop value
        // because if the beforelastletter is not monfasel, so it will be connected to the last
        // one, so they both form 1 path, this means that when we move item[0] both will be moved
        // to harakat layer then we will perform a cut(bef,shape) and then nothing to do with
        // the last letter because we have achieved the goal(all connected words are cut,
        // and all letters are moved to harakat layer)
        // unlike the stp=0, which depends to itterate through the last letter too for accessing it
        // and moving it to harakat layer

        // Check if the second last letter is in the list of separate letters
       if(arrayIncludes(stopAtZero,BeforeLastLetter)) StopAt = 0;

    
        // Handle specific cases based on the last letter's ASCII value
        if ((LastLetterAsci == 1609 || LastLetterAsci == 1610 )&& StopAt != 0) {// ي ى
            switch (words[wordIndex].length) {
                case 2:
                    ahrof[0].move(HarakatLayer, ElementPlacement.PLACEATBEGINNING);
                    moved = true;
                    len--;
                    Cut(1609, 2);
                    wordIndex++;
                    i--;
                    continue OUTER_LOOP; // Example: "في"

                case 3:
                    ahrof[0].move(HarakatLayer, ElementPlacement.PLACEATBEGINNING);
                    moved = true;
                    len--;
                    Cut(1609, 2);
                    Cut(words[wordIndex][0].charCodeAt(), 1);
                    wordIndex++;
                    i--;
                    continue OUTER_LOOP; // Example: "على"     

                case 4:
                    ahrof[0].move(HarakatLayer, ElementPlacement.PLACEATBEGINNING);
                    len--;
                    ahrof[0].move(HarakatLayer, ElementPlacement.PLACEATBEGINNING);
                    moved = true;
                    len--;
                    Cut(1609, 2);
                    Cut(words[wordIndex][1].charCodeAt(), 1);
                    wordIndex++;
                    i--;
                    continue OUTER_LOOP; // Example: "وعلى" 
                    // but what about "يجبى"

                default:
                    // Handle default case if needed
                    break;
            }
        }
        
        // Handle the case for specific word pattern (e.g., "شيء")
        if (BeforeLastLetter == 1610 && LastLetterAsci == 1569) { // Example: "شيء"
            ahrof[0].move(HarakatLayer, ElementPlacement.PLACEATBEGINNING);
            len--;
            Cut(1609, 2);
            ahrof[0].move(HarakatLayer, ElementPlacement.PLACEATBEGINNING);
            len--;
            moved = true;
            wordIndex++;
            i--;
            continue OUTER_LOOP;
        }

        // Iterate over each character in the current word
        INNER_LOOP: for (var j = 0; j < words[wordIndex].length - StopAt; j++) {
            // Get ASCII value of the current character
            currentAsci = words[wordIndex][j].charCodeAt();
        
        
            // If the character is a separate letter
            if (arrayIncludes(stopAtZero,currentAsci)) {

                // Move the first item to HarakatLayer if not already moved
                if (moved === false) {
                           if(ahrofLayer.pageItems[0] != null){
                                  ahrof[0].move(HarakatLayer, ElementPlacement.PLACEATBEGINNING);
                                  }
                          len--; // Reduce the count of items
                          }
                moved = false; // Reset move flag
                prevIsMonfasel = true; // Set flag for separate letters
            } else {

                // If the character is not a separate letter
                if (moved === false) {    // when moved is false, this means that the prev was monfasel
                    // Move the first item to HarakatLayer if not already moved
                    ahrof[0].move(HarakatLayer, ElementPlacement.PLACEATBEGINNING);
                    moved = true; // Set move flag to true so no need to move for the next j iteration
                    len--; // Reduce the count of items(paths)
                }
        
                // Handle cuts based on the position of the character in the word
                if (j < words[wordIndex].length - 1) { 
                   // Check if not the last letter
                    if (j === 0 || prevIsMonfasel) {
                        prevIsMonfasel = false; // Reset flag for separate letters
                        Shape = 1; // Shape type 1 for cutting
                        Cut(currentAsci, Shape); // Perform cut operation// beginning shape of letter
                    } else {
                        Shape = 2; // Shape type 2 for cutting// middle of word
                        Cut(currentAsci, Shape); // Perform cut operation
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        wordIndex++;
        i--;
        // we have adjusted values, for every i iteration=> one word passing
    }

    // Rename the Harakat layer to the name of the Quran text layer and remove the Quran text layer
    HarakatLayer.name = ahrofLayer.name;
    ahrofLayer.remove();
    QuranFile.close();
}


function Cut(currentAsci,Shape)
{  
    var btThyN = [1576,1578,1579,1610,1606,1609];

    //alert(asci)
    if(Shape==1)
    {
    
        if( arrayIncludes(btThyN  ,currentAsci)) // ب ت ث ي ن . ى لما تكون متصلة
        {
           //@include "35_G1_Cutting.jsx"
        }   
        if( currentAsci == 1605) // م
        {
           //@include "35_G2_Cutting.jsx"
        }
        if( currentAsci == 1601 || currentAsci == 1602 ) // ف ق
        {
           //@include "35_G3_Cutting.jsx"
        }
        if( currentAsci == 1603) // ك
        {
           //@include "35_G4_Cutting.jsx"
        }   
        if( currentAsci == 1580 || currentAsci == 1581 || currentAsci == 1582) // ج ح خ 
        {
           //@include "35_G5_Cutting.jsx"
        }
        if( currentAsci == 1587 || currentAsci == 1588) // س ش
        {
           //@include "35_G6_Cutting.jsx"
        }   
        if( currentAsci == 1593 || currentAsci == 1594) // ع غ
        {
           //@include "35_G7_Cutting.jsx"
        }
        if( currentAsci == 1604) // ل
        {
           //@include "35_G8_Cutting.jsx"
        }   
        if( currentAsci == 1607) // ه
        {
           //@include "35_G9_Cutting.jsx"
        }
        if( currentAsci == 1589 || currentAsci == 1590) // ص ض
        {
           //@include "35_G10_Cutting.jsx"
        }   
        if( currentAsci == 1591 || currentAsci == 1592) // ط ظ
        {
           //@include "35_G11_Cutting.jsx"
        }
    }


     if(Shape==2)
    {
        if( arrayIncludes(btThyN  ,currentAsci)) // ب ت ث ي ن 
        {
           //@include "35_G12_Cutting.jsx"
        }   
        if( currentAsci == 1605) // م
        {
           //@include "35_G13_Cutting.jsx"
        }
        if( currentAsci == 1601 || currentAsci == 1602 ) // ف ق
        {
           //@include "35_G14_Cutting.jsx"
        }
        if( currentAsci == 1603) // ك
        {
           //@include "35_G15_Cutting.jsx"
        }   
        if( currentAsci == 1580 || currentAsci == 1581 || currentAsci == 1582) // ج ح خ 
        {
           //@include "35_G16_Cutting.jsx"
        }
        if( currentAsci == 1587 || currentAsci == 1588) // س ش
        {
           //@include "35_G17_Cutting.jsx"
        }   
        if( currentAsci == 1593 || currentAsci == 1594) // ع غ
        {
           //@include "35_G18_Cutting.jsx"
        }
        if( currentAsci == 1604) // ل
        {
           //@include "35_G19_Cutting.jsx"
        }   
        if( currentAsci == 1607) // ه
        {
           //@include "35_G20_Cutting.jsx"
        }
        if( currentAsci == 1589 || currentAsci == 1590) // ص ض
        {
           //@include "35_G21_Cutting.jsx"
        }   
        if( currentAsci == 1591 || currentAsci == 1592) // ط ظ
        {
           //@include "35_G22_Cutting.jsx"
        }
         if( currentAsci == 1609) // ى
        {
           //@include "35_G23_Cutting.jsx"
        }
    }
}


